# Bayesian regression with distributions for x and y points

Tags: regression, bayesian

I am trying to work out the best way to sample the pdf of a set of calibration parameters for an instrument for sizing aerosol particles. We use a (small) number of different calibration particle samples with (assumed) Gaussian distributions of known mean size and variance to relate the instrument response to particle size. The instrument response is essentially a voltage (represented as a 12bit number) for each detected particle (i.e., thousands of points).
We assume that the relationship between this observed value and scattering cross section (i.e., the intensity of the light scattered into the detector by the particle) is linear and those are the parameters we want to estimate. The relationship between the cross section and the particle size is a known but non-linear and not invertible function that doesn't have a simple analytical form.

The instrument response also includes some (a priory unknown) noise and a systematic bias due to the optical setup that tends to detect some fraction of particles at a smaller signal than it should. So the noise is possibly non-Gaussian and biased but in a first step we could assume this noise to be Gaussian. (There might be a way to clean out the observed data in a separate step to address those issues.)

So essentially I am trying to estimate the parameters of a linear model where I observe a distribution of measured values and I know the distribution of the independent variable but not the exact value that lead to a certain observed point. Since the distribution of the predictor values can be broad with respect to the instrumental resolution, the distributions in x and y-direction might also be correlated to some extent.

A previous approach just used the modes of the two distributions to derive the slope and intercept of the calibration line making Gaussian assumptions for the distributions to estimate the uncertainties. However given the shape of the distributions, especially in the observed values, the mode is not a terribly good statistic to describe this. We also tried a bootstrap approach randomly sampling both distributions but there the correlation between the x and y distributions is not taken into account and I am not sure this gives us the correct uncertainties in the fit parameters.
I believe that there should be a clean way to sample the full posterior pdf for those fit parameters but I'm not a statistics expert and just can't quite work out what the best approach is. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I believe in a linear model with Gaussian measurement noise something in the line of the Kalman Filter should probably be the way to head. A more general approach for other forms of noise and nonlinearity should be Sequential Monte-Carlo methods, e.g. a Particle Filtering approach.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in a direction, I'll read up on that.